# Selenium Chrome WebDriver throwing null exception on .NetCore 3.0

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am running Selenium C# on .NET core 3.0 and it looks like the driver that I am using is not compatible and I get null driver exception. This is the setup I am running my selenium C#:

1. .NET Core 2.1
2. Windows 10
3. Chrome Version 78.0.3904.70
4. Packages - [Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42QGE.png)

Comment: Can you provide more information? Maybe a complete stacktrace and so on?

Comment: Please provide some code that you have tried or errors you have encountered. Also add more tags so the question is visible to a larger audience

Comment: 'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\\.nuget\packages\selenium.webdriver\3.10.0\lib\netstandard2.0\WebDriver.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.